# Linux: shell builtin string matching

Tags: bash, parsing, shell, wildcard

I am trying to become more familiar with using the builtin string matching stuff available in shells in linux. I came across this guys [posting](http://www.unix.com/aix/85016-split-filename-print-2-different-headings.html), and he showed an example

```
a="abc|def"
echo ${a#*|}    # will yield "def"
echo ${a%|*}    # will yield "abc"
```

I tried it out and it does what its advertised to do, but I don't understand what the `$,{},#,*,|` are doing, I tried looking for some reference online or in the manuals but I couldn't find anything. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

[This article in the Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) says that the `#` operator deletes the shortest possible match on the left, while the `%` operator deletes the shortest possible match on the right.

So `${a#*|}` returns everything *after* the `|`, and `${a%|*}` returns everything *before* the `|`.

If you had a situation that called for greedy matching, you'd use `##` or `%%`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

```
${string%substring}
```

> Deletes shortest match of $substring
>   from back of $string.

```
${string#substring}
```

> Deletes shortest match of $substring
>   from front of $string.

EDIT:

> I don't understand what the $,{},#,*,|
>   are doing

I recommend reading [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/regexp.html#REGEXREF)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, ${somename} will substitute the contents of a defined parameter:

```
mystring="1234567"
echo ${mystring}    # produces '1234567'
```

The % and # symbols are allowing you to add commands that modify the default behavior.

The asterisk '*' is a wildcard; while the pipe '|' is simply a matching character.  Let me do the same thing using the matching character of '4'.

```
mystring="1234567"
echo ${mystring#*4}  # produces '567'
```

Answer (score 1):

Those features and other similarly useful ones are documented in the [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC31) section of the Bash Reference Manual. Here's another really good [reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).